Audio amp split supply VSS/VEE current requirements?
Say a class AB audio amp IC (something like LM1875) specifies xx amps for operation. How much of that needs to go to on VEE? Could I wire the main supply to VSS and just use a charge pump for VEE? Or does it need to be an even split (current-wise) between VSS and VEE?
This is for a DC-only design.

Think of the LM1875 as a big, high-powered op-amp. It has the same input terminals as an op-amp:

+Vcc (op-amp V+)
-Vee (op-amp V-)
In+ (op-amp +)
In- (op-amp -)
Output (op-amp out)

You'll notice that there's no 'Vss'. Maybe you meant -Vee tied to GND for single-ended?
Regardless, -Vee is the negative rail that supplies the output pair and it draws as much current as Vcc, but not at the same time.
Think about it: a Class-AB amplifier like the LM1875 is also called a 'push-pull' driver, owing to its output structure that uses separate high-side (push) and low-side (pull) drivers.
When the output swings positive, the high-side driver sources current from Vcc to the load ('push'); when it swings negative, the low-side driver sinks current from the load to -Vee ('pull').
Therefore for split-supply operation -Vee needs to be the same size as Vcc, since they're handling the same amount of power but in opposite directions and at different times.
If your intent is to run the LM1875 single-ended, you would normally tie -Vee to GND and only provision power to Vcc. Note that you will have to level-shift your input somehow to accommodate that, ideally to Vcc/2.
One more thing. If your intent is for DC operation (that is, no blocking cap on the output), you will need to use bipolar supplies. Otherwise, if you use single-ended what you get is a Class A with idle power at 25%. That's why the LM1875 datasheet shows a 2200uF cap to the load when single ended, but no cap for split-rail.
